# Enable Activiti logging

Tags: business-process-management, java.util.logging, bpmn, activiti

I want to confirm if Activiti provides logs to see what's going on in Activiti like when a user logs in, when and which process is started, tasks are assigned and completed and by whom.
Currently Activiti is logging on console which is not showing the above required logs. I've tried changing log level from FINE to FINEST in logging.properties file but nothing happened.

Does Activiti provide logging containing this level of details and if not, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ACT_HI_*` tables might work for you as they log what is going on.

You may need to modify history level, check how to do that in the documentation: http://activiti.org/userguide/#historyConfig

Answer (score 4):

Activiti is using slf4j logging since 5.12 , you might need to check this section of their user guide to properly configure the logging :
http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#loggingConfiguration